How to get dotnet 8 azure function to run on an M3 chip inside a docker container?
I haven't had to ask a question here in ages but alas, I just became a new Mac user (MacBook Air M3) as well as a new docker user so I am beyond lost.
I am currently successfully getting my functions project to run locally on a docker container; however, when I actually execute a function in this project, I get a strange error and a 500 result.
The error I'm getting is.
[2024-06-05T02:59:36.903Z] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PAL_SEHException'
[2024-06-05T02:59:36.907Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=204.
[2024-06-05T02:59:36.907Z] dotnet exited with code 134 (0x86). .
[2024-06-05T02:59:36.938Z] Executed 'Functions.PdfUpload' (Failed, Id=6e29bc1c-ad6b-411d-9a4e-fa4f2265e952, Duration=174ms)
[2024-06-05T02:59:36.938Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.PdfUpload. System.Private.CoreLib: dotnet exited with code 134 (0x86). .

Here is my docker file.
# Use the .NET SDK image to build the application
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
ARG TARGETARCH

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PdfUploader/PdfUploader.csproj", "PdfUploader/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["SharedKernel/SharedKernel.csproj", "SharedKernel/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]

RUN dotnet restore "PdfUploader/PdfUploader.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PdfUploader"
RUN dotnet build "PdfUploader.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Publish the application
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
RUN echo $TARGETARCH
RUN dotnet publish "PdfUploader.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 as base

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm=true

# Set up necessary directories with the correct permissions
ARG APP_UID=1000
ARG APP_GID=1000
RUN mkdir -p /home/.azurefunctions && \
    chown -R ${APP_UID}:${APP_GID} /home/.azurefunctions

USER ${APP_UID}

ENV WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER_DOTNETISOLATED=0
ENV FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME="dotnet-isolated"
ENV AzureWebJobsStorage="xxx"
ENV AppConfigConnection="xxx"
ENV ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ENV ServiceBusConnection="xxx"
ENV EventHubConnection="xxx"
ENV SignalRConnection="xxx"

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

EXPOSE 7071

ENTRYPOINT ["func", "start", "--dotnet-isolated"]

I'm currently running rosetta on my docker desktop. As far as I've read up on, the strategy here should be to build a target image against linux/amd64 and use rosetta to emulate that.
My entire goal is to get my function to run locally so I can spin it up in my test project and run integration tests on it. I have no interest in actually deploying this to an app service so my approach was to setup an image with azure functions core tools and run it the same way I run it in my IDE
Can any docker experts help me perhaps build a simpler docker file that will run correctly?

I would suggest try and run a sample function trigger in your docker first and check if it works. to create a sample function. you can use command func init --worker-runtime csharp --docker-only. and then create a sample trigger using func new and try executing it.

and add AzureWebJobsStorage = <actual storage account connection string> instead of UseDevelopmentStorage=true in your Dockerfile

It looks like adding ENV DOTNET_EnableWriteXorExecute=0 as an env variable worked

So I tried adding an environment variable
ENV DOTNET_EnableWriteXorExecute=0.
And this fixed the issue. The function runs correctly. I had tried this a few days ago with no luck, it seems in order for this to work you need to make sure you are using --platform switches in your docker file and run command as well as making use of the $BUILDPLATFORM and $TARGETARCH commands in your docker file. I learned how to do this at this link.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-multiplatform-container-support/
And here is the git thread where they suggest using DOTNET_EnableWriteXorExecute=0
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/102509
